# React Native - Fetch Body with Square Bracket

Tags: react-native

How to fetch POST in React Native for body/query with square bracket?

Like :
        `user[email]`

Here's my code :

```
 fetch('url/users/sign_in/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'user[email]': this.state.email,
      'user[password]: this.state.password
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `user` an object.

```
"user": {
    "email": this.state.email,
    ...
```

Comment: save my day! thanks man, i just start with react native hehe @gnCupo